# How to display the total amount in Paypal shopping cart details

Tags: javascript, paypal, sdk, cart, display

In the Paypal shopping cart details, is there a way to display the total amount (unit_amount * quantity)
instead of unit_amount only in my case I want to display 13.00€ instead of 6.50€
I'm using the javascript SDK

```
items: [{
  name: '2 x Gauffres',
  description: 'Chantilly, Nutella',
  unit_amount: {
    currency_code: 'EUR',
    value: 6.50
  },
  quantity: 2
}]
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4M1V.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are including a quantity in the name (2 x Gauffres), you could conceivably set quantity:1 and have the value be 13. That would be the only way to change what your screenshot shows, but could be more confusing since a quantity:1 would show in some views.

---

The separate logged-in experience shows the unit_amount*quantity and individual unit_amount in separate places, so there's that.

[image]